# Searching in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, checkbox, find, has-many

I have two models: Inbox and Equipments. They have has_many relation :through => :inbox_equipments

In Inbox view I have the next code

```
<%= form_for @inbox, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_area :number, placeholder: "Enter inbox number" %>

    <% Equipment.all.each do |equipment| %>
        <%= check_box_tag :equipment_ids, equipment.id, @inbox.equipments.include?(equipment), :name => 'inbox[equipment_ids][]' %>
        <%= equipment.name %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

I need text area for find (or filter) desired value of equipment in check_box_tag

Like this:

```
<%= form_tag equipment_index_path, :method => 'get', :id => "equipments_search" do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
<%= submit_tag "Find", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
```

Help, please.

Comment: I'm writing an answer which _may_ help. You should also be aware that `check_box_tag` won't treat that element as a member of your form - might be worth changing to `f.check_box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although your description was not the best, I think you're looking for [**ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

I would do this:

---

**Call From Ajax**

Ajax will allow you to pull the other form from your Rails app as a partial, appending it as required. This will give you the ability to treat the form as an asynchronous request, removing any issue from the form itself

Here's what I'd do:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {

    $.ajax({
       url: "controller/search",
       data: $("input[name=inbox[equipment_ids]").serialize(),
       error: function(data) {
          alert(data)
       }
    });

});

#config/routes.rb
match 'search(/:search)', :to => 'controller#search', :as => :search, via: [:get, :post]

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def search
     @results = Model.where(:id => params[:equipment_ids])
     respond_to do |format|
         format.js
     end
end

#app/views/your_controller/search.js.erb
$("form").append(data)
```

This won't work out of the box, but it will give you some ideas as to what you can do